Issues with importing custom modules in jupyter notebook
So let's say we have a file structure as follows,
#Note: Not the actual directory structure, but a similar one
root../
 tests../
 src../
    __init__.py
    utils../
       __init__.py
       data.py
       pipeline.py
    sqlal../
       __init__.py
       sql_alchm.py
    test.py
 process.ipynb

Here is an example of data.py
from abc import ABC

class DataStrategy(ABC):
    pass

Here is an example of test.py
from utils.data import DataStrategy

class TestPipeline(DataStrategy):
    pass

Now I try to run all the imports in my jupyter notebook process.ipynb, I get an error as follows
import os
from src.test import Test Pipeline

#rest of the code in the cell
.....
.....

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

But if I run the file test.py I am not getting the error, Is this error has something to do with the scope of the notebook... or am I missing something?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your error doesn't match the code samples you've provided, which makes this somewhat difficult to debug - can you [edit] one or the other so they're compatible with each other?

It is not about the scope of Jupyter Notebook; it is about the import mechanism of Python.  If you update the code in test.py with the from .utils.data import DataStrategy, it will work in process.ipynb
`. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/13080899.

Hey, it works now, I was caught up with this issue many times but now I know, thanks!   @Ugurcan
